# Архитектура статистики с группировкой по диапазонам

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, проектирование

Нужно сделать на подобие такой штуки с группировкой по h , d, w, y:
(только не проценты , а значения).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется кафка куда складываются сообщения

Куда должны прийти это структура такого вида. Это как суммарно агрегационная результирующая сущность. Замечу что в одной сущности могут быть несколько полей (Likes\View допустим) диапазонов.

```
{
    ItemId: 1,
    Likes: {
         current: 3,
         prevHour: 4,
         prevWeek: 5,
    },
    Views: {
         current: 33,
         prevHour: 44,
         prevWeek: 55,
    }
}
```

Что я пытался

1. Использовать KSQLDB ,
   сделал агрегации вида:

   stats_likes_h
   stats_likes_w
   stats_views_h
   stats_views_w

Потом эти stream join в один, но оказывается что на текущий момент в KSQLDB никак нельзя взять со смещением офсет. Т.к. нужно не последние "корзинки" брать , а последние значение предыдущего часа\месяца\недели\года.

2. хотел сделать MongoDB + свой сервис который разгребает очередь KAFKA , но тут возникла проблема , если 1 сообщения = 1 update в базу, нагрузка очень высока. Если пытаться в коде делать Kafka batching то возникают проблемы с commit таймаутами , идемпотентностью и т.д. т.к. для этого кафка не предназначена.
3. дошли руки до TimescaleDB
   Тут есть материализованные представления с просчетом, соответственно и функция LAG\LEAD которые смогли сделать то что нужно

   select lag(value, 1) over (order by bucket), lag(value, 1*24) over (order by bucket), lag(value, 1*24*7) over (order by bucket)  from stats_likes_h  order by bucket desc limit 1

Так же и для view, а потом при выборки join. Но если у тебя много сущностей, а не только Likes | Views , то колво join так же увеличатся, а материализованное просчитанное представление НЕЛЬЗЯ сделать поверх другого просчитанного представления.

Я не чувствую что вариант с timescaleDB очень оптимальный. Вопрос куда смотреть ? Что еще можно пощупать? **Какие еще базы данных существуют с continues queries(иногда называют continiues aggregation или materialize continiues aggregation)?** В Apache там хрен ногу сведет , штук 20 похожих проектов, возможно не от апача...

В общем думаю ктото делал подобные вещи, жду рекомендаций.

Comment: Посмотрите InfluxDB. У самого руки не дошли, но по описаниям довольно многообещающе и мне его рекомендовали. https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/continuous_queries/  Это contignous query для предыдущей версии, сейчас вышла 2.0 как я понял там все надо делать только на языке flux, что может быть не привычно

Comment: @Mike до смотрел inluxdb , версию 1.* я как понимаю они vse, а в 2.* там супер неудобный , сложный , запутанный синтаксис , там все ноют от него, говорят верните sql , все их форумы завалены жалобами и вопросами... Но спасибо. Мб кто еще чтото подскажет?